# Apache causes 2 zombie processes after install certbot

Tags: apache2, process

I've tried to restart apache, reboot the system, but the 2 zombie processes does not disapear. This happend after installing certbot.

Z       2041    4991 apache2 
Z       2041    4992 apache2

Kill apache would not be a good solution due to this is a webserver.

Does anybody have an idea to solve this?

Comment: You needn’t `kill` Apache, but a `sudo service apache2 restart` should resolve the issue. This issues a “graceful” restart command so that currently running threads exit before they are eliminated and the service restarted. This process is rarely ever detected by visitors to your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: if you have custom logs definied in :80 ports config file comment them out them, you should not use if you redirect 80 to 443 ports in the in the two config files the same log definition.